# A question asking for hardware recommendations got deleted, reasons?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A question I had asked, as shown below, was flagged as "Technical support request" even though I was asking for something that helps with obtaining "pre-purchase hardware recommendations" and had nothing to do with "supporting existing devices".

Is there a misunderstanding in the rules of this stack exchange?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the best close reason to have picked, to be fair, but the question itself is unequivocally off-topic: it's not asking for a recommendation of specific hardware for a specific task, it's asking us to recommend a website that has reviews/comparisons of 3D printers. Very different things, and I'm afraid that's not on-topic here.